Dynamic Aggregation and Relationships in Power BI
I’m working on a Power BI project, and I’m struggling with some issues related to aggregation and relationships. Here's the scenario:
I have a dataset where each row provides information about invoices that are either due or already paid. My dataset looks a little like this:
Store | Product | Value | Installment Number | Due Date | Payment Date | Purchase Date
What I’m trying to do is create another table that summarizes information for each date. For example, the new table should look like this:
Date       | Value Received | Value Expected
Where: Value Received = sum of Value where Payment Date = Date
and    Value Expected = sum of Value where Due Date = Date
How can I solve these issues? Is there a better way to approach this? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance! 
I already have a separate table with all possible dates, which I intended to use for this summary. However, I’ve encountered the following issues:
When I create a calculated column in the date table, I’ve tried using the following formula in a calculated column in the date table:
SUMX(
FILTER(
payment,
payment[Due Date] = summarize[Date]
),
payment[Value]
)
The resulting summary table doesn’t interact dynamically with filters applied to the original dataset. This is critical for my BI solution.
Relationship conflicts: If I try to link the date table to the dataset, I can’t simultaneously connect it to both the Due Date and the Payment Date fields because it creates ambiguous paths in the relationship model.

pls provide your sample data in the markdown table and also provide the expected output. https://tabletomarkdown.com/
